# Why is python skipping the header?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This program reads a csv file, and sanitizes it by checking each row of the csv against the dictionary's keys, and switching with the corresponding value if there's a match. Somehow, the header or first row of the csv file goes missing. I suspect this has to do with the open() function. Thanks in advance, all.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 
from csv import writer
from old_new import replacements_map


def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    # Open file in append mode
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)

def get_file_encoding(src_file_path):
    """
    Get the encoding type of a file
    :param src_file_path: file path
    :return: str - file encoding type
    """
    with open(src_file_path) as src_file:
        return src_file.encoding

data = input('Please enter filename: ')
data += ('.csv')

my_encoding = str(get_file_encoding(data))
df = pd.read_csv(data, encoding=my_encoding)

csv_rows = df.values.tolist()

sanitized_rows = []

for row in csv_rows:
    sanitized_rows.append(
        [(replacements_map[item] if (item in replacements_map) else item)
         for item
         in row]
    )

file = "Clean_Dataset.csv"
for row in sanitized_rows:
    append_list_as_row(file, row)
```

Comment: which header are you missing? header from reading or from  writing?

Comment: Writing, in the last two lines.

Comment: and that you are certain the reading has no missing data?

Comment: I'll print df to see if the reading has missed anything

Comment: The headers appear when I do: append_list_as_row('tempfile', df)

Comment: This, however, omits the header:
append_list_as_row('tempfile', csv_rows)

It looks like the append_list_as_row contains the issue.

Comment: haven't tested it, but consider calling `df = pd.read_csv(data, encoding=my_encoding, header=None)` when reading in the csv

Comment: It appears that the problem is with the append_list_as_row function. I'll look into the writer and writerow methods

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `get_file_encoding` function is broken. That just tries to open with the default encoding, and will fail if it isn't that encoding.

Comment: Courtesy of Ashish Greycube, I'm using

def get_file_encoding(src_file_path):
      encoding = chardet.detect(part.encode())['encoding']
      return encoding

To get the encoding. Source: https://github.com/frappe/frappe/pull/8061

Answer (score 0):

I"ve figured it out:

```
rawdata = open(file, "rb").read()
encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata)['encoding']
```

I believe that header=None does it.

From the docs "if column names are passed explicitly then the behavior is identical to header=None". By inference, it would seem that header=0 could preserve headers, since passing headers explicitly would seem to preserve those headers.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd
import chardet
import csv 
from csv import writer
import sys
from old_new import replacements_map


def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    # Open file in append mode
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)


def get_file_encoding(file):
    rawdata = open(file, "rb").read()
    encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata)['encoding']
    #encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata.encode())['encoding']
    return encoding

data = input('Please enter filename: ')
data += ('.csv')

my_encoding = get_file_encoding(data)
df = pd.read_csv(data, encoding=my_encoding, header=None, low_memory=False)

csv_rows = df.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)

sanitized_rows = []

for row in csv_rows:
    sanitized_rows.append(
        [(replacements_map[item] if (item in replacements_map) else item)
         for item
         in row]
    )

file = "Clean_Dataset.csv"

for row in sanitized_rows:
   append_list_as_row(file, row)
```